# Move FusionPBX db from PostgreSQL to SQLite

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, fusionpbx

Is it possible to configure FreeSWITCH to use SQLite for it's internal database, instead of the default PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

FreeSWITCH uses SQLite as it's default database. Certainly you can change it back to this. You need to make changes in a few places in the XML config files and in the SIP profile parameters. Off the top of my head:

/etc/freeswitch/autoload_configs/switch.conf.xml

```
Comment out:
<!-- <param name="core-db-dsn" value="XXXXXX" /> -->
Add the following line:
<param name="auto-create-schemas" value="true"/>
```

Next, in your SIP profiles, comment out or remove the following parameter:

```
<--<param name="core-db-dsn" value="pgsql://hostaddr=127.0.0.1 dbname=freeswitch user=freeswitch password='" />-->
```

Finally, rescan profile and reload XML in the FreeSWITCH console:

```
freeswitch> sofia profile <profile_name> [<rescan>|<restart>] reloadxml
```

Once you modify these parameters, restart FreeSWITCH:

```
systemctl restart freeswitch
```

And you should find FreeSWITCH will auto-create databases for the core and SIP profiles automatically.

I think this is most of it. There may be other databases for other modules like mod_callcenter or mod_fifo, but those DSNs are configured in their own config files. This should get you started with the core.